# The command "find" output an error message

Tags: shell, find

I would like to inquire about an error message that I get when I run the command "find". In the following paragraph, I will explain what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a parent folder. Inside this folder there are many subfolders. Inside each subfolder there are plenty of sub-sub folders. I would like to list the sub-sub folders that contain a specific number of files. I ran for loop as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
in=PATH_TO_THE_PARENT_FOLDER

for i in ${in}/*; do
find ${i} -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo -e $(find {} | wc -l) {}' | sort -n | grep -w 69 | awk '{print $2}' #69 represent the total number of files within a folder
done
```

This code output the following error message `sh: MPR_Range: No such file or directory`. I Googled looking for an explanation for what `sh: MPR_Range` means, but I couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have a file called `foo&bar`. `xargs` will now run the command

```
sh -c 'echo -e $(find foo&bar | wc -l) foo&bar'
```

That runs `echo` and `find` in the background, and two copies of `bar`. Similarly for `foo;bar`, and `$(bar)`.

Don't use `{}` in the argument to `sh -c`, instead, give the filename as a separate argument, i.e.

```
... |xargs sh -c 'echo -e $(find "$1" | wc -l) "$1"' sh {} | ...
```

In addition, you could use `find -exec` instead of `xargs`:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'echo ...' \;
```

I'm also not exactly sure if the `sort` is necessary, if you running `grep` to find lines with particular numbers anyway.

Comment: @goro, of course, for that to produce that error, you'd need to have some file with `MPR_Range` and other appropriate characters in the file name, but that looks like it would be the most likely explanation here